# Configure openejb autoconfig by Tomee with multiple datasources and miltiple apppication

Tags: persistence, openejb, apache-tomee

We use Tomee 1.7.1 jaxrs with multiple datasources and applications.
For example:

**App1 persistance.xml**

```
<persistence-unit name="DS1_PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>DS1</jta-data-source>
...
</persistence-unit>
```

**App2 persistance.xml**

```
<persistence-unit name="DS2_PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>DS2</jta-data-source>
...
</persistence-unit>
```

**tomee.xml**

```
<Resource id="DS1" type="DataSource">
    JdbcDriver  org.postgresql.Driver
    JdbcUrl     jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DS1
    UserName    postgres
    Password    123
    JtaManaged  true
    ValidationQuery select 1
    TestOnBorrow    true        
</Resource>

<Resource id="DS2" type="DataSource">
    JdbcDriver  org.postgresql.Driver
    JdbcUrl     jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DS2
    UserName    postgres
    Password    123
    JtaManaged  true
    ValidationQuery select 1
    TestOnBorrow    true        
</Resource>
```

**Deployment log:**

INFORMATION: Adjusting PersistenceUnit DS1_PU  to Resource ID 'DS1NonJta' from 'null'
INFORMATION: Adjusting PersistenceUnit DS2_PU  to Resource ID 'DS2NonJta' from 'null'

**Problem:**
 When I make a typo in a persistance.xml, f.e.

```
<persistence-unit name="DS2_PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>DS_WRONG</jta-data-source>
...
</persistence-unit>
```

app still deployes but use wrong data source:

INFORMATION: Adjusting PersistenceUnit DS2_PU  to Resource ID 'DS1NonJta' from 'null'

It seems that openejb takes first founded data source.
Can I disable this "feature"?